# Как вывести текст, заданный radio

Tags: javascript

Помогите плиз, должно быть элементарное решение, но туплю:
Есть радио список
-дерево
-трава
-поле
Человек видит этот список, выбирает "дерево", нажимает кнопку "Показать", а ему под кнопкой появляется значение "Высокое". Если же выбирает "трава", то появляется "зеленая". Ну и если "поле", то "широкое".

Comment: @Sintes, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: имеется в виду, что следует загрузить свой вариант решения на jsfiddle.net, и уже на примере описать, что именно не получилось. Тогда мы вероятнее всего сможем помочь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рабочий пример на [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/hBXnH/3/)
**html**

```
<form id="super-form">
    <input type="radio" name="object" value="tree" checked="checked" />
    <label>Дерево</label>
    <input type="radio" name="object" value="grass" />
    <label>Трава</label>
    <input type="radio" name="object" value="field" />
    <label>Поле</label>
    <hr/>
    <input type="radio" name="counter" value="1" checked="checked" />
    <label>Мало</label>
    <input type="radio" name="counter" value="2" />
    <label>Два</label>
    <input type="radio" name="counter" value="3" />
    <label>Три</label>
</form>
<button id="super-button" onclick="magicAction();">Сделать хорошо</button>
<div id="response"></div>
```

**javascript**

```
function magicAction() {
    var all_objects = document.getElementsByName('object'), //Все варианты объектов
        all_counters = document.getElementsByName('counter'), //Все наборы объектов
        object = getCheckedRadio(all_objects).value, //Выбранный объект
        counter = getCheckedRadio(all_counters).value, //Выбранный набор
        response = document.getElementById('response'), //Куда выводим результат
        output = '', //Итоговый текст
        object_text = '', //Текст для объекта
        counter_text = '', //Текст для набора
        delimeter = ' - '; //Разделитель между текстом для объекта и набора

    //Проверяем, на какую радиокнопку из группы "object" нажали
    switch (object) {
        case 'tree':
            object_text = 'Высокое';
            break;
        case 'grass':
            object_text = 'Зеленая';
            break;
        case 'field':
            object_text = 'Широкое';
            break;
    }

    //Проверяем, на какую радиокнопку из группы "counter" нажали
    switch (counter) {
        case '1':
            counter_text = 'Мало';
            break;
        case '2':
            counter_text = 'Два';
            break;
        case '3':
            counter_text = 'Много';
            break;
    }

    //Формируем результат
    output = object_text + delimeter + counter_text;

    //Выводим результат
    response.innerHTML = output;

}

//Функция, выбирающая отмеченную радиокнопку из списка
function getCheckedRadio(radio_group) {
    //Обходим весь список радиокнопок
    for (var i = 0; i < radio_group.length; i++) {
        var button = radio_group[i];
        //Нашли отмеченную
        if (button.checked) {
            return button;
        }
    }
    //Ни одна не отмечена
    return undefined;
}
```

Comment: Да, спасибо!
Только один нюанс: 
хотелось бы, чтоб результат не сразу появлялся, при выборе пункта, а только по нажатию отдельной кнопки "Применить". 
т.е.: выбираю "дерево" -> нажимаю "Применить" -> получаю "Высокое".


Comment: Обновил свой ответ под новые условия.

Comment: Шикарно!! Спасибо большое! Именно то, что нужно)

Comment: А вот если усложнить задачу и сделать две группы радио кнопок. Например: -дерево -трава -поле со своими значениями так и остаются, а вот к ним еще добавить одну группу: "мало" со значением (одно), "два" это (два) и "три" - это (много). Например, выбираем в первом списке "трава", а во втором - "три". Нажимаем кнопку "Получить результат" и получаем: "Зеленая-много". Был бы премного благодарен!!

Comment: @Sintes , готово. Переделал пример.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Выручаете!